# Frontend Build failed AWS Amplify Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tagName')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, aws-amplify

TL;DR: I can't tell why my React app is failing the frontend build on AWS Amplify.

Hello! I am new to deploying with AWS Amplify and needed some help demystifying the below logs.

```
2023-08-03T03:04:06.973Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2023-08-03T03:04:20.518Z [WARNING]: npm
s (including breaking changes), run:
                                 npm audit fix --force
                                 Run `npm audit` for details.
2023-08-03T03:04:32.538Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2023-08-03T03:04:32.895Z [INFO]: > trash5@0.1.0 build
                                 > react-scripts build
2023-08-03T03:04:34.328Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2023-08-03T03:05:15.189Z [INFO]: Failed to compile.
2023-08-03T03:05:15.193Z [INFO]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tagName')
2023-08-03T03:05:15.249Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-08-03T03:05:15.250Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-08-03T03:05:15.250Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-08-03T03:05:15.250Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

amplify.yaml / build settings in amplify

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

The only two error lines occur almost at the very end, but I cannot identify why. There is no 'tagName' being called in my code.

The React site loads just fine on my local computer using npm start and I also don't see any failures locally with npm build. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: What happens when you run `npm run build` on local?

Comment: It runs perfectly fine, nothing out of the ordinary